# ClearQuest - Calling queries via API?

Tags: api, clearquest

Is it possible to run CQ query, created in Native Client and saved on server, via CQ API calls?

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible, you would:

1. GetWorkSpace object
2. Iterate it to get QueryDef Object
3. Use QueryDef to get a ResultSet.

Check out Api notes here [GetWorkSpace](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc/default_topic.htm) for a starter...